# Ionic/Angular file corrupted on Android

Tags: angular, file, ionic-framework, download

I am trying to download files from an Spring Boot server. curl returns normal files. When downloading with angular

```
 const req = new HttpRequest<Blob>('GET', url, {
      responseType: 'blob',
      reportProgress: true,
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'x-auth': token
      })
    });
```

This results in files missing random chunks of data, different for each mobile phone, but fixed for one?! Images get corrupted so they can't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use 'responseType': 'arraybuffer'.

But I don't know why...